# Explain Mobile First app authenticity mechanism?

Tags: android, security, authentication, ibm-mobilefirst, token

I'm trying to understand the App Authenticity mechanism in Mobile First. But couldn't find much documentation on this. Could someone please explain,

1. How Mobile First generates and verifies auth token?
2. What is the algorithm used in app authenticity?
3. Is there any alternate for this (like JWT)?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you read [app auth documentation page](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/application-authenticity/)?

Comment: From memory Mobile First is based of Cordova and you might want to start your search there for [jwt](https://github.com/e-mission/cordova-jwt-auth)

Answer (score 0):

IBM MobileFirst Platform's Application authenticity algorithm and it's working is proprietary and cannot be shared.

Just as the user authentication is used to obtain and validate the identity of a user, an application authenticity mechanism is used to obtain and validate the identity of an application. Therefore, this process is referred to as application authenticity.

Application authenticity makes sure that any application that tries to connect to MobileFirst Server is authentic and was not tampered with or modified by some attacker.

You can read more about how to enable Application authenticity for MFP 8.0 [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/application-authenticity/):

Earlier versions [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_ibm_worklight_app_authentication_overview.html).